# How to get the Route id from subnet ID using aws java SDK?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I have value of subnet say subnet-c1dkeb9z . I just wanted to know its assocaited route id?

Answer (score 0):

To get Route information, you can use the AWS SDK for EC2.

A [Subnet](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/ec2/model/Subnet.html) object does not have a method that describes route information.

To get route information, Invoke the [describeRouteTables](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/ec2/Ec2Client.html#describeRouteTables-software.amazon.awssdk.services.ec2.model.DescribeRouteTablesRequest-) method. This returns a DescribeRouteTablesResponse object. Using this method, you can invoke the [routeTables](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/ec2/model/DescribeRouteTablesResponse.html#routeTables--) method, which returns a list of [RouteTable](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/ec2/model/RouteTable.html) objects.

Comment: I already have result of describeRouteTables. I just wanted to get route Information of subnets associated with particular instance.

Comment: When you call describeRouteTables, look at the use of Filers - https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/ec2/model/Filter.html.,